# LINQ to SQL, multiple table join, generated SQL missing 2nd INNER JOIN

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Can anyone tell me why the generated SQL does not contain a 2nd INNER JOIN?  It seems to have been replaced with a NULL check in the WHERE clause?  I'm not clear on why the 2nd INNER JOIN is not in the generated SQL.

C# code:

```
var cycleList = from o in entities.Orders
              join c in entities.Cycles on o.Id equals c.OrderId
              join calendar in entities.Calendars on c.CalendarId equals calendar.Id
            where o.UnitId == unitId && o.CompanyId == companyId
            select c.Id;
```

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT 
[Extent2].[Id] AS [Id]
FROM  [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Cycles] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[OrderId]
WHERE ([Extent2].[CalendarId] IS NOT NULL) AND ( CAST( [Extent1].[UnitId] AS int) = @p__linq__0) AND ( CAST( [Extent1].[CompanyId] AS int) = @p__linq__1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It looks like the query generator is optimizing your query.**

Since you are not selecting (*or using in your where clause*) any fields from the **Calendars** table in your query, only one join is done between the **Orders** table and the **Cycles** table. It's likely faster to check for the non-*NULL* foreign key than it is to join on a table from which no fields will be used.

Comment: You are exactly right, I tested with another field selection and it worked as expected.  Thanks for the quick response.